# How to split Flask Main file in multiple files and share Variable

Tags: python, flask

I have read alot about this but I just don't seem to figure it out... I should use `Blueprint` for this but the problem I am having right now is that I do not know how to pass my variable from my main file in my second file.

As an example :

```
/app
  /runserver.py
    /app
      init.py
      main.py
      second.py
```

Now I do have a dictionairy in my main that I fill. And I want to use it in my second file to adjust it etc. How will I be able to do this? Since I tried to import the files and tried:

```
import main
dictMain = main.dictFromMain
```

I thought this would be enough since I read it on different question on Stack Overflow but it doesn't seem to work!

**EDIT**: To sketch the problem further

More background : I am making a client - server application, the client is receiving and sending data from the server. But there is a difference is the data the client is sending. On one hand you have files and paramters which I want to 'capture' with my second file with ReST. And on the other hand I got a incomming stream which I 'capture' in my main file.

Example second file:

```
    @app.route('/uploads/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def get_files():
      if request.method == 'GET':
        sendDict = []
        for element in ctxList:
          for fileCtx in element['file']:
            d = { 'id' : element['id'], 'file': [ {'name': fileCtx['name'], 'uri' : fileCtx['uri'], 'path' : fileCtx['path'] } ] }
            sendDict.append(d)
    jsonString = jsonify(ctx=sendDict)
    return jsonString
```

But this code uses a dictionairy from my first file (the dict ctxList) I have no idea to get it out of my first file. I used to get a error when I did : `ctxList = mainFile.ctxList` that the module did not have this variable, but now I am getting a error that the first file does not know the URL structure ( /uploads/ from the second file).

Comment: *it doesn't seem to work* is not an error description. Do you get a traceback? If so, include that in your post.

Comment: Why not use [Flask globals](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-globals)

Comment: @akash-kothawale If I use those Flask Globals i'm getting : working outisde of application context.